# Date comparison differences

Tags: date

I've been trying to look online to find some place that explains if there is a difference between this two selects:

```
update  dim t
set t.ind = case  when  t.date<trunc(sysdate)
                                          and t.date<>to_date('01/01/0001','DD/MM/YYYY') then 1
                                   else 0
                        end
```

Or this one that has the does exactly the same, but with between :

```
update  dim_equip t
set t.equip_unrecovered_ind = case  when  t.equip_return_date_due  between  to_date('02/01/0001','DD/MM/YYYY')
                                          and trunc(sysdate-1) then 1
                                    else 0
                              end
```

I've checked the explain plan of both of them, they are exactly the same .

[image]

Comment: What is that you want to ask ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are logically different. You seem to be assuming the calendar starts at 0001-01-01. But Oracle's [date data type spans from -4712-01-01 to 9999-12-31](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#i54330).

The first query will get 1 for any BCE date in that range, as well as any CE date from 0001-01-02 up to today, and 0 for 0001-01-01 (00:00:00) and any date/time after midnight today. The second query will get zero for any BCE date.

There is no real practical difference unless you have BCE dates, of course. At least as long as any dates in your on 0001-01-01 are all at midnight.

The other difference is, as Gordon Linoff suggested, if your table's date values have a non-zero time component. The first query gets 0 for exactly midnight on the date you exclude, 0001-01-01 00:00:00. But it would get 1 for any other time that day, i.e. from 0001-01-01 00:00:01 to 0001-01-01 23:59:59. Assuming it is actually a date; if it's a timestamp then the precision makes a difference too. The second query gets 0 for any time that day, and only gets 1 from 0001-01-02 00:00:00.

---

You said the plan is exactly the same for both queries. The graphical representation you're showing might be the same, but that's just the access and join path the optimiser chose, it is not the entire path. The optimiser is choosing a full table scan for both, but that doesn't tell you anything about what data will be returned. If you include the access and filter predicates then you'll see they are different, reflecting the different logic. They may still end up with the sae result set, but that depends on your actual data.

As @a_horse_with_no_name said in a comment on your earlier question, look at the plain text execution plan, or use a tool that gives you more information (but please still use the text version in questions, not an image). See the documentation for [how to get more information](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_xplan.htm#ARPLS70125).

Comment: The thing is, the first one run a lot longer then the second one, what can cause this diffrences?

Comment: @Yossi - if you edit your question to show the full (text!) execution plan for each query there might be some difference you haven't seen. But they are both having to read and update every row in the table. It may just be down to cacheing, with the second query using data from the block cache without having to hit physical disk again. Try running both statements multiple times in different orders.

Comment: How can i get the full execution plan? I only have a button/f5 in plsql developer that gives me an explain plan output

Comment: @Yossi - did you follow the link at the end of my answer?

Answer (score 1):

On first glance, assuming that `t.date` has no time component, then the two should be the same.  And I even think for your logic, a time component wouldn't make a difference.

There is a slight difference because the second condition uses different dates.

In general, both methods have to read all the data, do some date arithmetic and then assign a value to all rows.  The reading and writing are going to dominate the performance of the query, given that you have simple comparisons.  So, there is no reason to expect one to be much better or worse than the other, and trying to optimize this code is a micro-optimization, where the effort can probably better be spent somewhere else.

Comment: The thing is, the first one run a lot longer then the second one, what can cause this diffrences?